# why cppcheck say "Function parameter should be passed by reference"?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

This is the code of cppcheck show warning "[event.cpp:20]: (performance) Function parameter 'path' should be passed by reference."

```
void
event::set_path(const std::string path)
{
    this->_path = path;
}
```

but other code including string parameter dont show this warning, like:

```
int
watcher::init_watch(const struct stat *sb, std::string path, bool linked)
{
    int wd;
        ....
}
```

why?

Comment: Passing arguments and returning values by `const` *values* is broken, because it inhibits all forms of move semantics.

Answer (score 9):

Because it should! There is no reason to pass a const copy, you can't modify it anyway, so why copy it. In the worst case it's going to have to allocate memory for a brand new string, then copy the string one byte at a time. In the best case it might do some internal reference counting magic, but if you just passed it by reference then you're at most copying a single pointer to the new point in the stack. pass by `const std::string& path` - It will be much faster.

The path parameter in `init_watch` should be passed in by const reference too, because that is going to make a copy too for no reason.

Comment: I cannot agree with the second argument. Are you sure that `path` is not being modified in `init_path`? If it is then a copy can be made on invocation already.

Comment: yeah you're right , i just curious about why cppceck dont give me waring in second case.. maybe cppcheck dont care about this error?

Comment: As the comment above says, and they are right, there might be a case for passing a non-const copy in if you're going to manipulate the string further, but there is no reason to pass in a const copy, which is why cppcheck only complains about the first case

Comment: @fayewu it isn't an error. The contents of "`....`" very much matter in interpreting cppcheck's *advice*